# Vertica - Join on MAX(Date)

Tags: vertica

I m trying to replicate this sql syntax in Vertica, but it returns "ERROR: Subqueries in the ON clause are not supported".
The aim is to join two tables, table1 and table2, on *column* and *date*, if a.date = b.date or the closest but lesser b.date.
Any hint?

```
SELECT      *
FROM        table1 a
LEFT JOIN   table2 b 
ON a.column = b.column
AND         b.Date = (SELECT   MAX (b2.Date) 
                      FROM     table2 b2 
                      WHERE    a.column = b2.column
                      AND      b2.Date <= a.Date)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertica has something handier for that: the *event series join*. With that, you can `OUTER JOIN` two tables so that they match the same or the immediately preceding value of the join column of the other table. The predicate is `INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE` instead of an equi-predicate.

Here's an example with the oil pressure curve and the engine rpm curve with the timestamp matching only once.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS oilpressure;                                                                                                               
CREATE TABLE oilpressure (
 op_vid,op_ts,op_psi
) AS (
          SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-04-01 07:00:00', 25.356
UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-04-01 07:00:12', 35.124
UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-04-01 07:00:23', 47.056
UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-04-01 07:00:34', 45.225
)
;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS revspeed;
CREATE TABLE revspeed (
 rs_vid,rs_ts,rpm
) AS (
          SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-04-01 07:00:00', 2201
UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-04-01 07:00:10', 3508
UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-04-01 07:00:20', 6504
UNION ALL SELECT 42,TIMESTAMP '2020-04-01 07:00:30', 6608
)
;
-- without
\pset null '(null)'
SELECT *
FROM oilpressure
LEFT OUTER JOIN revspeed
ON op_vid=rs_vid AND op_ts=rs_ts ;
-- out Null display is "(null)".
-- out  op_vid |        op_ts        | op_psi | rs_vid |        rs_ts        |  rpm   
-- out --------+---------------------+--------+--------+---------------------+--------
-- out      42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:00 | 25.356 |     42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:00 |   2201
-- out      42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:12 | 35.124 | (null) | (null)              | (null)
-- out      42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:23 | 47.056 | (null) | (null)              | (null)
-- out      42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:34 | 45.225 | (null) | (null)              | (null)

-- with
SELECT *
FROM oilpressure
LEFT OUTER JOIN revspeed
ON op_vid=rs_vid AND rs_ts INTERPOLATE PREVIOUS VALUE op_ts;
-- out  op_vid |        op_ts        | op_psi | rs_vid |        rs_ts        | rpm  
-- out --------+---------------------+--------+--------+---------------------+------
-- out      42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:00 | 25.356 |     42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:00 | 2201
-- out      42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:12 | 35.124 |     42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:10 | 3508
-- out      42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:23 | 47.056 |     42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:20 | 6504
-- out      42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:34 | 45.225 |     42 | 2020-04-01 07:00:30 | 6608
```